# Powershell script design write message body to log

Tags: email, powershell, foreach

I'm trying to parse through my Outlook inbox and match certain messages and then, for each of those matches, write the email message body to my Application log. My code so far is below but I'm finding that the script is writing the same message for each match. Meaning, the last message body that the script stores, gets written X number of times for each of the matches that the filter catches.

```
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]  
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
 $inbox = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox) 
 $filter = (%{$inbox.items | Where {$_.SenderName -match ‘TestUser’ -and $_.UnRead -eq $true}})
 $filter.count

 foreach ($msg in $filter)
 {
 $MsgBody = $filter | select-object Body | format-table -HideTableHeaders -Wrap | Out-String
}

for ($i = $filter.count; $i -gt 0 ; $i --) {
Write-eventlog -logname Application -source "TestAlerts" -eventID 100 -entrytype Information -message "$MsgBody"
#$($msg)[$i].UnRead -eq $false - this still isn't working either.

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($i = $filter.count; $i -gt 0 ; $i --) {
 $msg = $filter[$i]
 $MsgBody = $msg | select-object Body | format-table -HideTableHeaders -Wrap | Out-String
 Write-eventlog -logname Application -source "TestAlerts" -eventID 100 -entrytype Information -message "$MsgBody"
}
```

Comment: That worked - thanks!! The only change I needed to make was to  set $i -gt -1 since it would fail to write on the last message.